# Twitter-based application in android

Tags: android, database, twitter, hashtag

I am trying to build an application for android devices. It is supposed to be similar to youtube's "related videos" part, or for example, in amazon.com you see a part that says people who viewed this book also viewed these etc. I want to, for example look at the hashtag called "hobbit" and try to find which movies were also watched by these users. I do not really know where to start can anyone help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if you have any knowledge of Android, so first you should start at the [developer page](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) and get a basic understanding of Android development.

Twitter also has a [developer page](https://dev.twitter.com/)

You can parse tweets and look at their hashtags.
Tweets always have Entities that provide metadata and additional contextual information about content posted on Twitter.

In those Entities you can get the hashtags

```
"hashtags":[{"indices":[32,36],"text":"lol"}]
```

After you got those hashtags you can search for it using the Twitter API.